# Proof Using Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on a problem in [*Kurzweil & Stellmacher's*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387405100) introductory finite group theory that looks like this:

> Let $A, B$, and $C$ be subgroups of the finite group $G$. Prove that if $B \leq A$, then $$|A : B| \geq |C \cap A : C \cap B|.$$

On my scratch paper, I am working **backward** like these:
$$\begin{align}
|A : B| &\geq |C \cap A : C \cap B| \tag{1}\\
&\Updownarrow\\
\frac{|A|}{|B|} &\geq \frac {|C \cap A|} {|C \cap B|} \tag{2}\\
&\Updownarrow\\
\text{(3a)} \quad|A| \geq |C \cap A| \quad   &\land \quad \text{(3b)} \quad  |C \cap B| \geq |B| \tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, proving (3a) is straightforward since $A \supseteq (C \cap B)$, but proving (3b) will be counter-intuitive, since for sure $(C \cap B) \subseteq B$.

Am I on the wrong track? Any help or hints would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $(2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$ is *not* true. For example, $\frac{4}{5} > \frac{2}{3}.$ Also $(3b)$ is not true.

Comment: @Krish : So, I guess I am on the wrong track then. Any suggestion on the right strategy?

Comment: One clarification: by $|A:B|$ you mean the number of distinct left cosets of $B$ in $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal K$ be the set of left cosets of $B$ in $A$, and $\mathcal L$ be the set of left cosets of $C\cap B$ in $C\cap A$. Consider the mapping $f:\mathcal L\longrightarrow \mathcal K$ defined by: $f:x(C\cap B)\mapsto xB$, for $x\in C\cap A$. Note that it is well defined, since $x\in C\cap A$ implies $xB\in \mathcal K$. If $f(x(C\cap B))=f(y(C\cap B))$, for $x,y\in C\cap A$, i.e. $xB=yB$, then $x^{-1}y\in C$ (since $x,y\in C$) and $x^{-1}y\in B$ (since $xB=yB$). Hence $x^{-1}y\in C\cap B$, so $x(C\cap B)=y (C\cap B)$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

So, $|\mathcal L|\leq|\mathcal K|$, i.e. $|C\cap A:C\cap B|\leq |A:B|$.

Comment: Thanks! Have green check-marked and upvoted yours.

Comment: You're welcome!